# Compiling Mono (linux) with static glibc

Tags: linux, mono, static-libraries

Is it possible to compile [mono](https://github.com/mono/mono), for linux, that statically references glibc? I need to run mono on an older OS that doesn't have the required glibc 2.15 (or greater).

**UPDATE 1**

I have set all the environment variables for flags to be sent to the compiler/linker.

```
# echo $CFLAGS
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Here is the -help from the `./configure --help` for mono. I have set all the *FLAGS with the value above.

```
Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  CCAS        assembler compiler command (defaults to CC)
  CCASFLAGS   assembler compiler flags (defaults to CFLAGS)
  CPP         C preprocessor
  CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor
  XMKMF       Path to xmkmf, Makefile generator for X Window System
```

After setting up all the environment variables to staticly link libgcc and libstdc++, I ran the following commands.

```
# ./configuire --prefix=/usr/local/mono
# make
# make install
```

The output output of the first command indicates that it has gotten my flags...

```
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local/mono'  'CFLAGS=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' 'LDFLAGS=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' 'CPPFLAGS=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' 'CXXFLAGS=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' 'CPPFLAGS_FOR_EGLIB=' 'CFLAGS_FOR_EGLIB=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' '--disable-embed-check' '--with-libgc-threads=pthreads' '--enable-parallel-mark' 'CPPFLAGS_FOR_LIBGC=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -DGC_LINUX_THREADS -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -DUSE_MMAP -DUSE_MUNMAP -g -Wall -Wunused -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wno-cast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wno-switch -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-unused-value -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DUSE_COMPILER_TLS -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' 'CFLAGS_FOR_LIBGC=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -mno-tls-direct-seg-refs' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
```

...however, doing ldd on the output indicates that it didn't statically link glibc.

```
# ldd /usr/local/mono/bin/mono
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xb77a2000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0xb773a000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0xb7731000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb772c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7710000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7557000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77a3000)
```

I would expect to see `libc.so.6` embedded at this point.

How do I get mono statically linking against all these shared libraries?

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the output for my build commands.

```
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mono
```

[Output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b7bd0c35bf607c62c4b)

```
# make
```

[Output](https://gist.github.com/theonlylawislove/421954b4990c5dd64311)

```
# make install
```

[Output](https://gist.github.com/theonlylawislove/321480e80d126b122d34)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libc >= 2.15 is actually not required by Mono. Few seconds ago I've build and tested latest Mono on Debian Wheezy with libc=2.13 — it's OK.

You can check it by reading [packages info from official mono repository](http://origin-download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages), for example:

```
Package: mono-2.0-gac
Source: mono
Version: 3.12.0-0xamarin3
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Debian Mono Group <pkg-mono-group@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 65
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.13) | libc6.1 (>= 2.13) | libc0.1 (>= 2.13), libmono-corlib2.0-cil (>= 3.2.8), libmono-security2.0-cil (>= 3.0.6)
```

Comment: When I run it on Fedora 14 (glibc 2.13), the application fails to start with the ld saying I need at least glibc 2.13.

Comment: Also, I just download that package, and it contains only the gacutil.exe.

Comment: Update: Your right, it only requires 2.13, which is my version! Turns out, running the make from mono's source adds the 2.15 requirement. Xamarin (or whoever) is doing something different when building the deb distribution packages which only requires 2.13.

Comment: If there is incorrect deps in [.rpm packages from official repo](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#centos-fedora-and-derivatives), you can install .deb package on Fedora using [alien](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/).